# Is geocoding with Nominatim available for all the countries?

Tags: geocoding, nominatim, malaysia

I am trying to geocode an address using Nominatim for Malaysia but it cannot recognize it using his page: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/. Is Nominatim available only for certain countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite of the low rate for the post, there is a question has to be answered.

**Nominatim is available for all the countries.**

Check [the web map](https://vision.eos.com/maps/shared/5bd1b50c-7266-4686-969d-1654b7cab26a) showing the geocoding quality across the globe
[image]

1. For every country, 100 random points generated
2. Points locations were geocoded (using reverse geocoding) to obtain the address and coordinates
3. Obtained addresses were geocoded using the "address" field

The map connects locations obtained by reverse geocoding and locations obtained by direct geocoding

Comment: The link that you provided (https://aspectum.com/maps/shared/5bd1b50c-7266-4686-969d-1654b7cab26a) is outdated, I am getting the `404 Error Sorry, the page is not found!`.

Answer (score 5):

Based on Nominatim [FAQ](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/FAQ#Why_wasn.27t_anything_found_for_my_search.3F), there are many reasons of why your search didn't get any result:

> **Why wasn't anything found for my search?**
>
> There are a number of reasons why no result may have been found:
>
> 1. There is no data currently in OSM which matches your criteria. Data
>      which you expect to match may be defective in some way. For example,
>      if you search for "Springfield, Massachusetts", it may not be found
>      if the state border has been damaged and no longer encloses
>      Springfield.
> 2. The place is spelled wrongly. The name has to be the same as in the
>      OSM database, Nominatim is not able to correct bad spelling.
> 3. The search query does not use the correct encoding.

There is no information of whether nominatim is for specific countries or not, but I believe it is not for specific countries because they include a code for every country in this globe.